# GoTo Implementation: First-class navigation for the VBE

Tags: c#, rubberduck

ReSharper has a very handy feature that's particularly useful when coding against abstractions. Since coding against abstractions is something that can also be done in VBA, the next release of [rubberduck](/questions/tagged/rubberduck) is going to include that functionality as well:

[image: right-click on an interface method and select "Go to implementation" to list all implementations of that method]

---

The click handler for the code pane context menu simply calls the paremeterless overload of `FindAllImplementations`:

```
private void _findAllImplementationsContextMenu_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    FindAllImplementations();
}

private void FindAllImplementations()
{
    var selection = IDE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection();
    var progress = new ParsingProgressPresenter();
    var parseResult = progress.Parse(_parser, IDE.ActiveVBProject);

    var implementsStatement = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaces()
        .SelectMany(i => i.References.Where(reference => reference.Context.Parent is VBAParser.ImplementsStmtContext))
        .SingleOrDefault(r => r.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName && r.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));

    if (implementsStatement != null)
    {
        FindAllImplementations(implementsStatement.Declaration, parseResult);
    }

    var member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers()
        .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));

    if (member == null)
    {
        member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceMembers()
            .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Project == selection.QualifiedName.Project
                                  && m.ComponentName == selection.QualifiedName.ComponentName
                                  && m.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));
    }

    if (member == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    FindAllImplementations(member, parseResult);
}
```

There's also a public overload that takes a `Declaration` target, so that the functionality can be used from the *Code Explorer*'s own context menu:

```
public void FindAllImplementations(Declaration target)
{
    var progress = new ParsingProgressPresenter();
    var parseResult = progress.Parse(_parser, IDE.ActiveVBProject);
    FindAllImplementations(target, parseResult);
}
```

And lastly an overload that takes parse results, in case there's a readily usable and resolved parse tree to use:

```
public void FindAllImplementations(Declaration target, VBProjectParseResult parseResult)
{
    IEnumerable<Declaration> implementations;
    if (target.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class)
    {
        implementations = FindAllImplementationsOfClass(target, parseResult);
    }
    else
    {
        implementations = FindAllImplementationsOfMember(target, parseResult);
    }

    if (implementations == null)
    {
        implementations = new List<Declaration>();
    }

    var declarations = implementations as IList<Declaration> ?? implementations.ToList();
    var implementationsCount = declarations.Count();

    if (implementationsCount == 1)
    {
        // if there's only 1 implementation, just jump to it:
        ImplementationsListDockablePresenter.OnNavigateImplementation(IDE, declarations.First());
    }
    else if (implementationsCount > 1)
    {
        // if there's more than one implementation, show the dockable navigation window:
        try
        {
            ShowImplementationsToolwindow(target, declarations);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // the exception is related to the docked control host instance,
            // trying again will work (I know, that's bad bad bad code)
            ShowImplementationsToolwindow(target, declarations);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var message = string.Format(RubberduckUI.AllImplementations_NoneFound, target.IdentifierName);
        var caption = string.Format(RubberduckUI.AllImplementations_Caption, target.IdentifierName);
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Then we have specialized methods, depending on whether we're looking for implementations of an interface, or of a specific member:

```
private IEnumerable<Declaration> FindAllImplementationsOfClass(Declaration target, VBProjectParseResult parseResult)
{
    if (target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Class)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = target.References
        .Where(reference => reference.Context.Parent is VBAParser.ImplementsStmtContext)
        .SelectMany(reference => parseResult.Declarations[reference.QualifiedModuleName.ComponentName])
        .ToList();

    return result;
}

private IEnumerable<Declaration> FindAllImplementationsOfMember(Declaration target, VBProjectParseResult parseResult)
{
    if (!target.DeclarationType.HasFlag(DeclarationType.Member))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var isInterface = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaces()
        .Select(i => i.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.ToString())
        .Contains(target.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.ToString());

    if (isInterface)
    {
        return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(target.IdentifierName);
    }

    var member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceMember(target);
    return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(member.IdentifierName);
}
```

Here's the presenter implementation that handles the UI part:

```
public class ImplementationsListDockablePresenter : DockablePresenterBase
{
    public ImplementationsListDockablePresenter(VBE vbe, AddIn addin, SimpleListControl control, IEnumerable<Declaration> implementations)
        : base(vbe, addin, control)
    {
        BindTarget(implementations);
    }

    private void BindTarget(IEnumerable<Declaration> implementations)
    {
        var listBox = Control.ResultBox;
        listBox.DataSource = implementations.Select(implementation => new ImplementationListItem(implementation)).ToList();
        listBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayString";
        listBox.ValueMember = "Selection";
        Control.Navigate += ControlNavigate;
    }

    public static void OnNavigateImplementation(VBE vbe, Declaration implementation)
    {
        vbe.SetSelection(new QualifiedSelection(implementation.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName, implementation.Selection));
    }

    private void ControlNavigate(object sender, ListItemActionEventArgs e)
    {
        var implementation = e.SelectedItem as ImplementationListItem;
        if (implementation != null)
        {
            OnNavigateImplementation(VBE, implementation.GetDeclaration());
        }
    }

    SimpleListControl Control { get { return UserControl as SimpleListControl; } }
}
```

It works beautifully. How would you improve this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers()
    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));

if (member == null)
{
    member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceMembers()
        .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Project == selection.QualifiedName.Project
                              && m.ComponentName == selection.QualifiedName.ComponentName
                              && m.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));
}
```

This has a crash-causing bug.  You need to change the top `.SingleOrDefault()` to match the bottom one.

---

Right here, you need to ensure the members are of the same interface - not just have the same name:

```
if (isInterface)
{
    return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(target.IdentifierName);
}

var member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceMember(target);
return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(member.IdentifierName);
```

Otherwise, you return all the `IClass2_DoSomething`s along with the `IClass1_DoSomething`s.

A simple `.Where()` will fix it:

```
if (isInterface)
{
    return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(target.IdentifierName)
           .Where(item => item.IdentifierName == target.ComponentName + "_" + target.IdentifierName);
}

var member = parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceMember(target);
return parseResult.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers(member.IdentifierName)
       .Where(item => item.IdentifierName == member.ComponentName + "_" + member.IdentifierName);
```

Thanks for helping me develop patches for these problems, @Mat's Mug

Answer (score 1):

Small note. In some places we're referring to the editor as `vbe` or `VBE`. In others we're referring to it as `IDE`. We should pick one or the other.

Comment: yeah.. remnants of RD 1.0...